# Deploy Qt Design Studio Project for Webassembly

Tags: qt, webassembly, emscripten, qt6

I am using Qt 6.3.2 and im on a M1 Mac.

I am trying to build a Qt Design Studio Project for webassembly but I have trouble to install the Designer Components for Webassembly.

To use a Design Studio Project, you have to install the Designer Components to your Installation, which I did like stated in the documentation:[Adding Qt Quick Designer Components to Qt Installations](https://doc.qt.io/qtdesignstudio/quick-converting-ui-projects.html#adding-qt-quick-designer-components-to-qt-installations).

This works fine when I build it for Mac but I cant get it to work with WASM. Do I need to build the components in a specific way for em++?

When I use the components like stated in the docs I get the following error message:

```
em++: warning: unrecognized file type: `/Users/marius/Qt/6.3.2/wasm_32/./qml/QtQuick/Studio/Effects/libquickstudioeffectsplugin.dylib`.  Mapping to `-lquickstudioeffectsplugin` and hoping for the best [-Wmap-unrecognized-libraries]
em++: warning: unrecognized file type: `/Users/marius/Qt/6.3.2/wasm_32/./qml/QtQuick/Studio/Application/libquickstudioapplicationplugin.dylib`.  Mapping to `-lquickstudioapplicationplugin` and hoping for the best [-Wmap-unrecognized-libraries]
em++: warning: unrecognized file type: `/Users/marius/Qt/6.3.2/wasm_32/./qml/QtQuick/Studio/EventSimulator/libquickstudioeventsimulatorplugin.dylib`.  Mapping to `-lquickstudioeventsimulatorplugin` and hoping for the best [-Wmap-unrecognized-libraries]
em++: warning: unrecognized file type: `/Users/marius/Qt/6.3.2/wasm_32/./qml/QtQuick/Studio/EventSystem/libquickstudioeventsystemplugin.dylib`.  Mapping to `-lquickstudioeventsystemplugin` and hoping for the best [-Wmap-unrecognized-libraries]
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -lquickstudioeffectsplugin
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -lquickstudioapplicationplugin
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -lquickstudioeventsimulatorplugin
wasm-ld: error: unable to find library -lquickstudioeventsystemplugin
em++: error: '/Users/marius/Documents/Git/emsdk/upstream/bin/wasm-ld @/var/folders/k3/prb53mjs50sf220pb_trz4fc0000gn/T/emscripten_7udnbcap.rsp.utf-8' failed (returned 1)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I tried to build the components for other architectures or as a static library.

Comment: Should check if these files actually exist in `/Users/marius/Qt/6.3.2/wasm_32/./qml/QtQuick/Studio/` or anywhere else in the Qt installation directory. Not all Qt modules are available on WebAssembly, they are still porting them one-by-one and each Qt release has more WebAssembly modules. I have not tested Qt 6.3 but at least on 5.15 designer plugins were not available.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yes I build the missing module from source and installed it there. The library is there but its a .dylib that seems to be incompatible with em++. I will just stick to the Qt creator and wait until they might port them.